# Is there a way to display console data in HTML with an onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display console data on my localhost whenever a button is clicked. How would I display such data on my website? When I click the button, I see the data in the console and all I need now is for the actual data to be visualized in a grid view or similar.

I'm rather new to this, hence why I'm here.

```
function ipLookUp () {
  $.ajax('http://ip-api.com/json')
  .then(
      function success(response) {
          console.log('User\'s Location Data is ', response);
          console.log('User\'s Country', response.country);
          getAddress(response.lat, response.lon)
},

function fail(data, status) {
          console.log('Request failed.  Returned status of',
                      status);
      }
  );
}

function getAddress (latitude, longitude) {
// $.ajax('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=AIzaSyAq3EWvKjpBxwlovWzvnH5xj9zXVk9_C10')

  $.ajax('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + latitude + ',' +longitude + '&key=AIzaSyAq3EWvKjpBxwlovWzvnH5xj9zXVk9_C10')
  .then(
    function success (response) {
      console.log('User\'s Address Data is ', response)
    },
    function fail (status) {
      console.log('Request failed.  Returned status of',
                  status)
    }
   )
}
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  // check if geolocation is supported/enabled on current browser
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
   function success(position) {
     // for when getting location is a success
     console.log('latitude', position.coords.latitude, 
                 'longitude', position.coords.longitude);
     getAddress(position.coords.latitude, 
                position.coords.longitude)
   },
function error(error_message) {
    // for when getting location results in an error
    console.error('An error has occured while retrieving location', error_message)
    ipLookUp()
 });

} 
else {
  // geolocation is not supported
  // get your location some other way
  console.log('geolocation is not enabled on this browser')
  ipLookUp()
}
```

The output in the console looks like this:

```
{status: "success", country: "Sweden", countryCode: "SE", region: "E", regionName: "Östergötland", …}
as: "AS205016 HERN Labs AB"
city: "Linköping"
country: "Sweden"
countryCode: "SE"
isp: "HERN Labs AB"
lat: 58.4116
lon: 15.6268
org: ""
query: "77.111.247.148"
region: "E"
regionName: "Östergötland"
status: "success"
timezone: "Europe/Stockholm"
zip: "582 22"
```

Comment: You're instructing your code to write things to console via `console.log`. What you need to do is to write that information to the `document` object. Create HTML elements with defined IDs, query them, and update their `innerHTML`.

Comment: BTW please don't post your keys around.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I deleted the old key and got myself a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create HTML elements and define IDs for easier access through selectors ([getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) for example).

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="coords"></p>
    <p id="country"></p>
    <p id="address"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you can access the [element and update it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

```js
function getAddress (latitude, longitude) {
  $.ajax('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + latitude + ',' +longitude + '&key=KEY')
  .then(
    function success (response) {
      document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = 'User\'s Address Data is ' + response;
    },
    function fail (status) {
      console.log('Request failed.  Returned status of',
                  status)
    }
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopes this helps you ! you can read more about Javascript from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide)

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body onload="fetchCurrentLocation()">


        <div id="list"></div>


        <script>

            function renderList(response) {
                let ul = document.createElement('ul');
                if (response.status === "OK ") {
                    let list = response.results;
                    for (let index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
                        let item = list[index];
                        let li = document.createElement('li');
                        li.innerHTML = `<span> ${item.formatted_address} </span>`;
                        ul.appendChild(li);
                    }
                } else {
                    let li = document.createElement('li');
                    li.innerHTML = `<span> Something goes wrong </span>`;
                    ul.appendChild(li);
                }
                document.getElementById('list').appendChild(ul);
            }

            function ipLookUp(params) {
                $.ajax('http://ip-api.com/json')
                    .then(
                        function success(response) {
                            console.log('User\'s Location Data is ', response);
                            console.log('User\'s Country', response.country);
                            getAddress(response.lat, response.lon)
                        },

                        function fail(data, status) {
                            console.log('Request failed.  Returned status of',
                                status);
                        }
                    );
            }


            function getAddress(latitude, longitude) {
                $.ajax('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + latitude + ',' + longitude + '&key=AIzaSyAq3EWvKjpBxwlovWzvnH5xj9zXVk9_C10')
                    .then(
                        function success(response) {
                            console.log('User\'s Address Data is ', response)
                            renderList(response);
                        },
                        function fail(status) {
                            renderList(response);
                            console.log('Request failed.  Returned status of', status)
                        }
                    )
            }

            function fetchCurrentLocation() {
                if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
                    // check if geolocation is supported/enabled on current browser
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                        function success(position) {
                            // for when getting location is a success
                            console.log('latitude', position.coords.latitude,
                                'longitude', position.coords.longitude);
                            getAddress(position.coords.latitude,
                                position.coords.longitude)
                        },
                        function error(error_message) {
                            // for when getting location results in an error
                            console.error('An error has occured while retrieving location', error_message)
                            ipLookUp()
                        });

                }
                else {
                    // geolocation is not supported
                    // get your location some other way
                    console.log('geolocation is not enabled on this browser')
                    ipLookUp()
                }

            }

        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```